# How to make fixed aspect ratio, highlight and rule of thirds enabled by default?

Tags: gimp

How can I enable `Highlight`, `Rule of thirds` and `Fixed aspect ratio of 1080x1080` as default settings in GIMP for the selection tool?

Comment: Hi levu, Welcome to GD.SE! Can you tell us what you have tried? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. What does "Highlight" mean for GIMP? Rule of thirds for a selection doesn't really make sense; Are you trying to setup guides or view rule of thirds when using the crop tool? There're tool options for making a selection.

Comment: I'm voting to close this one as off-topic / tech support

Comment: Looks like a perfectly valid question to me...

Comment: @xenoid I agree with Luciano.  This is more of a tech-support question and less of a design one.  See [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the options as you want them (for all the Tools, plus FG/BG colors, pattern, font, brush, etc....). Set the current tool to what you want the default tool to be. Then go to *Edit>Preferences>Tool options*, un-check *Save tool options on exit* and hit *Save tool options now*. From then on Gimp wil start up with all these options.

You can in addition save specific sets of options/settings for most tools, see the diskette icon at the bottom of the Tool options dialogs.